# Creating block of IDs on a List based on a field

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with several columns. I need to create an ID for a block when my Column1="AA". If a previous block contains an ID, I should have ID+1.

I have something like this:

```
Column0|Column1|
23|AA
23|AA
23|AX
23|AX
23|AX
23|AA
23|AA
23|AX
23|AA
```

And I need something like this:

```
Column0|Column1|Column2
23|AA|1
23|AA|1
23|AX|
23|AX|
23|AX|
23|AA|2
23|AA|2
23|AX|
23|AA|3
```

In different words, I wanna create IDs (in seq.) to identify blocks of information that contain Column1=AA.

Side note: The order from the list is already the one that I needed.

So, should I use foreach or for loop? I am getting confused when I try to apply my ideas:

(_gDataID is my list; Columns Type will contain my AA or AX or ... ; SeqNumberOfTempCycle is the column that I wanna set with the "ID block" )

```
     int lastseq = 0;


            for (int i = 0; i < _gDataID.Count; i++)
            {

                if (_gDataID[i].Type.ToString() == "AA")
                {
                    //Does the previous columns has a seq?
                    if (_gDataID[i-1].SeqNumberOfTempCycle.ToString() == null)
                    {                         
                        _gDataID[i].SeqNumberOfTempCycle = lastseq + 1;
                        lastseq = lastseq + 1;

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        _gDataID[i].SeqNumberOfTempCycle = lastseq;

                    }
                }

            }
```

As you may notice, my ideas are not working well. First, I cannot do this:

```
_gDataID[i].SeqNumberOfTempCycle = lastseq + 1;
```

And my for loop is not looping and setting up the field properly.

Comment: You could iterate through the list and keep current seqnumber of the string(eg "AA") and every time you encounter  new block, you increment  current seqnumber for corresponding string.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to update counter if there are gaps between the sequence of tokens. In that case, Use Dictionary to remember previously encountered token:

```
Dictionary<string, int> tokens = new  Dictionary<string, int>();
int i = 0;
while(i < gDataID.Count)
{
   string dataToken = gDataID[i].Type.ToString();
   if(!tokens.ContainsKey(dataToken)
   {
     tokens.Add(dataToken, 0);
   }
   tokens[dataToken]++;

   While(i < gDataID.Count && gDataID[i].Type.ToString() == dataToken)
   {
       gDataID[i].SeqNumberOfTempCycle =  tokens[dataToken];
       i++;
   }
}
```